# Apache 404 error Log to a different log file

Tags: apache, logging

We want to separate 404 not found errors into a different log file.
Now our log file (apache) that writes this errors is in "access.log" file.

We want to have 404 not found errors for example in notfound.log

I did a test writting in apache2.conf:

```
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" notfound
```

and in VirtualHost of apache sites-available:

```
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/not-found.log notfound expr=.*404.*
```

But I got **"error in condition clause"**

I tried to set a env variable in VirtualHost too:

```
SetEnvIf expr .*404.* httpcode
```

And call it in CustomLog expr but didn't work. Somebody can help us, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach could work if you install the custom Apache module [SetEnvIfPlus](http://opensource.adnovum.ch/mod_setenvifplus/#ResponseSetEnvIfPlus). This should allow you to set an environment variable using the `ResponseSetEnvIfPlus` directive and then use that envirionment variable to force a custom log file.

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to [Apache CustomLog Manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog). It says

> The CustomLog directive is used to log requests to the server. A log
>   format is specified, and the logging can optionally be made
>   conditional on request characteristics using environment variables.
>
> The first argument, which specifies the location to which the logs
>   will be written, can take one of the following two types of values:
>
> file A filename, relative to the ServerRoot. pipe The pipe character
>   "|", followed by the path to a program to receive the log information
>   on its standard input.

So you can specify a program path instead of a log file path and can handle requests by that program. You can find more about piped logs [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/programs/rotatelogs.html)